# A question on using ontologies for text classification

Tags: classification, sparql, ontology

I want to classify short pieces of text (neuroscience-related), using an ontology ([NIF](https://github.com/SciCrunch/NIF-Ontology/tree/master/ttl)). I have read some papers, but non of those went through the whole procedure of performing an ontology-based classification. Therefore, I wanted to double check and see if I got it right:

*Feature Extraction:* First, we will use the ontology for annotating (tagging) the text with ontology concepts. We will parse the text and annotate terms that can be found from the ontology using the class of those terms in the ontology.

I guess the accuracy of the annotation process can be increased by using techniques such as finding semantic similarities between ontology terms and terms in the text. Also, by using techniques such as [lemmatization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html).

Using ontology and a rule-based classification system, there is no need for learning and we can move towards classification.

Then, for the classification phase and since we're using a rule-based classifier, we will classify the text according to the classes assigned to the text. Is this correct? Also, can we move up in the ontology and use super-classes in annotation in order to reduce the number of tags (classes) used in the classification?

My other question is: Are there enough benefits for using ontologies in classification? Because I read in [a paper](http://folk.uio.no/rdridan/papers/pacling07-qc.pdf) that using ontologies actually decreases the accuracy! What are those benefits? What does using meaningful tags from the ontology allow us to do that arbitrary terms don't?

Comment: If you're automatically tagging with a rule-based classifier how can an ontology compared to a set of arbitrary terms reduce the accuracy? Accuracy is a function of your tagger, which is only working with terms either way. Don't move up the ontology to reduce the number of tags as you'll lose information, if you tag something as nif:"Double Cone Cell" then it's also a nif:"Cell" but the opposite isn't true. The benefits come when you query your ontology because you can use subclasses and the relationships between them. Plus the formal definitions, shareable data, self-documenting etc. etc....

Comment: @PaulBrown Thanks for the input. May I ask you a favor? I am a researcher and have some questions regarding ontology-based classification. Seems you know it pretty well (or at least better than me!). Is it possible for you to set up a Skype or Zoom meeting, so I can discuss my questions further? I can write you in an email or here, but I think it will take a long time and I have a deadline soon! Thanks in advance.